# Get file names from 1 to 5

Tags: php

The title is not more clear but the question container is more clear.

I have this code:

```
if (!file_exists(**I_WANT_HELP_ON_THIS**)) {
    header("Location: error.php");
}
```

I want to check if the following files ( file1.txt - file2.txt - file3.txt - file4.txt - file5.txt ) exists (but with a simple code) .. So what should be **I_WANT_HELP_ON_THIS** ?

I don't want to use:

```
if (!file_exists('file1.txt')) {
    header("Location: error.php");
}

if (!file_exists('file2.txt')) {
    header("Location: error.php");
}

etc...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use logical OR `||` operator to get a single condition:

```
if (!file_exists('file1.txt') || !file_exists('file2.txt') 
    || !file_exists('file3.txt') || !file_exists('file4.txt') || !file_exists('file5.txt')) {
    header("Location: error.php");
}
```

Comment: i was thinking the same, but if there are many files i'd suggest the array approach just cause it is a bit more readable. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @flynorc, we have the exact title: *Get file names from 1 to 5*. Otherwise, the question should be elaborated

Comment: @flynorc, that's ok

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this by using an array where you define all files (filenames) which you would like to check and then loop over that array like so

```
$files = array("file1.txt", "file2.txt",...);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if(!file_exists($file) {
        header("Location: error.php");
        exit(); //or just break; if you still need to do something else
    }
}
```